# Making Tab Persist when Reloading Page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to modify Gaya Design's Tabbed Content ([Available Here](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/animated-tabbed-content-with-jquery/)) to have the current tab persist when the page is reloaded, yet have it change when a new tab is clicked. I've already changed it a little to be able to change default tab by using a `PHP` `GET` variable.  The current condition of the page I'm working on can be viewed [here](http://www.aifittingpsroto.com/samples/).

So here's my likely scenario.  If you've clicked on the link above, you'll see I'm working on a simple PHP shopping cart.  Now when a user clicks an add link, it has to reload the page, and when it does that it resets the tab.  So, I'm thinking this should easily be solved with a cookie that updates whenever a new tab is clicked....I'm just not too sure how to go about this.  Any thoughts, suggestions, or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current JS:

```
var TabbedContent = {
init: function() {  
    $(".category").click(function() {
        var background = $(this).parent().find(".selected");
        $(background).stop().animate({
            left: $(this).position()['left']
        }, {
            duration: 350
        });
        TabbedContent.slideContent($(this));
    });
},
slideContent: function(obj) {
    var margin = $(obj).parent().parent().find(".sliderContainer").width();
    margin = margin * ($(obj).prevAll().size() - 1);
    margin = margin * -1;

    $(obj).parent().parent().find(".displayContent").stop().animate({
        marginLeft: margin + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 1
    });
},
gotab: function( obj ) {
    var background = $(obj).parent().find(".selected");
    $(background).stop().animate({
        left: $(obj).position()['left']
        }, {
            duration: 1
        });
        TabbedContent.slideContent( $(obj) );
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    TabbedContent.init();
});
```

Here's how a tab is initialized when it is linked to:

```
<?php
// Load a specific tab if required
if(isset($_GET['tab'])) {
    // Array storing possible tab IDs
    $tabChoices = array('productsTab', 'specsTab', 'brochuresTab', 'bannersTab', 'kitsTab', 'displaysTab');
    $tab = '';
    if(in_array($_GET['tab'], $tabChoices)) $tab = $_GET['tab'];
    // Default to productsTab if not in array list
    else $tab = 'productsTab';
    // JS to actually do the switch
    echo '<script>$(document).ready(function() {TabbedContent.gotab($("#' . $tab . '"))});</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're painting yourself into a corner by inline scripting a solution. You should always only have one $(document).ready... call in your entire product, in order to avoid order dependent explosions in code, and have a clear point of entry.

That said, you are almost there. Instead of calling a function, assign a value.

```
echo "<script>var selectedTab=$tab;</script>"
```

Then during your initialization function, make use of that value. My example is in global scope. There may be a race condition if you try to assign it to a namespace. In that case, try putting that script at the bottom of the page.

One more suggestion, have one and only one function handle all of your animations calls for that object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using get/post params you could use hash; creating links like this in the tabs:

```
<a class="tab_item" href="#one_go" id="one">
```

And then put this in the javascript:

```
var gototab = document.location.hash.replace('_go',"")
if(gototab){
    $(gototab).each(function(){ 
        var pos = $(this).prevAll(".tab_item").length,
            left = pos * $(this).outerWidth(),
            margin = pos * $(this).parent().parent().find(".slide_content").width() * -1;
        $(this).parent().find('.moving_bg').css('left',left)
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".tabslider").css('margin-left',margin)
    })
}
```